Integrate PGCRYPTO and azure/gcp/aws KEY VAULT in PostgreSQL
Syntax of PGCRYPTO -->>> PGP_SYM_ENCRYPT('Jona', 'AES_KEY')
If i want to get this AES_KEY or any other key that is created in key vault into this PGSQL How can i do it? Im not talking about executing them in python or java if i want to use it within db is it possible if so how can you help me out? even about executing them in python and java can also be listed ill use them if needed later on.
I have researched in lot of place no useful info found in GPT and GEMINI Struggles

please add what you have tried

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@Aswin T A Please check the below answer and let me know if there is any issue


Integrate PGCRYPTO and azure/gcp/aws KEY VAULT in PostgreSQL

AFAIK, there is no built-in function in Azure Postgres SQL to integrate with azure key vault and fetch the key from it.
To workaround you can try store the key value directly in azure Postgres SQL from key vault using Python as below:
#To get kay value from Key vault
from  azure.identity  import  ClientSecretCredential
from  azure.keyvault.keys  import  KeyClient

TENANT= 'secret'
CLIENT_ID = 'client-id'
CLIENT_SECRET= 'client-secret'
credential = ClientSecretCredential(TENANT,CLIENT_ID,CLIENT_SECRET)
key_client = KeyClient(vault_url="https://pdstackkv.vault.azure.net/", credential=credential)

key = key_client.get_key("sample1")
print(key.name)

#store this value in  azure Postgres SQL 
import psycopg2 

# Update connection string information 
host = "<server-name>" 
dbname = "<database-name>" 
user = "<admin-username>" 
password = "<admin-password>" 
sslmode = "require"  

conn_string = "host={0} user={1} dbname={2} password={3} sslmode={4}".format(host, user, dbname, password, sslmode) conn = 
psycopg2.connect(conn_string)

# Insert some data into the table 
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO tablename (name) VALUES (key);")


